# Flink + RichAsyncFunction + Cache with Checkpoint/Savepoint support

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink app with a RichAsyncFunction that does async queries to an external database. The function is using a Guava cache. This is working perfectly, however it currently doesn't get included in checkpoints/savepoints. Is there a way I can get the cache data included in Checkpoints/savepoints?

I notice that RichAsyncFunction doesn't support the state functionality at all. Does this mean I can't serialize my cache to checkpoints/savepoints?

There is one Guava cache for the entire Flink app which might make this
scenario simpler.

Is there a recommended way to handle this situation?

FYI, I need lock-free concurrency support including check-and-set, which is offered by both java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap and Guava's cache, but not Flink's MapState. Is it in line with Flink best practices to use a Guava cache?

Comment: For those interested in this question, be aware that it was also posted to the flink user mailing list, so you may find answers there: https://lists.apache.org/thread/oof8hmojdd6nzpy13pwrnjksqmpl3hlw

Comment: Yes, I asked the same question on both the user@flink mailing list and here at Stack Overflow. Should I only ask on one platform and not the other? I haven't gotten any substantial replies to either.

Comment: My concern is to avoid having members of the Flink community make duplicated efforts. It's hard enough to try to answer all of the questions, let alone answer them twice.